# How to disable <select> option based on other <select> option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is 2 combobox with the same options as well as the value. So when the user selected python in first combobox, the python option in second combobox will be disable. But when I try this is wouldn't work. Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<select name="first_combobox">
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="lua">Lua</option>
</select>

<select name="second_combobox">
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="lua">Lua</option>
</select>
```

**JS (jQuery) :**

```
$("select[name=first_combobox]").change(function(){
    if ($("select[name=first_combobox]").val() === $("select[name=second_combobox]").val()) {
        $("select[name=second_combobox] option[value=" + $("select[name=first_combobox]").val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("select[name=second_combobox] option[value=" + $("select[name=first_combobox]").val() + "]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$("select[name=first_combobox]").change(function(){
    $("select[name=second_combobox] option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select[name=second_combobox] option[value=" + $("select[name=first_combobox]").val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fptgv4x/)

Comment: Ah ! Works fine for me now ! Removing the `[value=]` on the `removeAttr`, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly want you need. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#theSelect").change(function(){
   $("select[name=second_combobox] option").removeAttr("disabled");
   $("select[name=second_combobox] option[value=" + $("select[name=first_combobox]").val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "theSelect" name="first_combobox">
 <option value="python">Python</option>
 <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
 <option value="lua">Lua</option>
</select>

<select id="theSelect" name="second_combobox">
 <option value="python">Python</option>
 <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
 <option value="lua">Lua</option>
</select>
```